# Calling a C function and get the string output in C#

Tags: .net, c, marshalling

I want to have a function in C language file which can return string as output and I want to access that function from Managed Code i.e C# and get that string as return value. Any help or links related to this would be great for me.

Comment: With all due respect, have you tried searching the net for it?

Comment: ya I Tried searching for it but as I am not good in C language that is why I am not able to create a function in C language which returns string and that function I can access in C# for that string as output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a method in a common library, or a custom library? The more common ones can be found on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/). If not, MSDN has an article on [Platform Invoking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) using [`DllImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Method would be in custom library and somewhat would look like-- void TEST(char optVal[])
{
 
} So I want to get the optVal in in my C# code.

Comment: @Vikram: a `void` function doesn't return anything. What's the signature of the function in the C library you're looking to retrieve? I'll write an import for you based on that.

Comment: The signature of the function would be like void Test(char* optVal)
{}. Kindly tell me how would I be able to get the optVal's value in my C# code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brad for helping me out till here, I am able to get the output reference in C# by using the following import funct - [DllImport(@"C:\Test\CalledDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)] public static extern void SnmpTest([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]StringBuilder sb);

Answer (score 0):

You would use [Platform Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx) to call your C function. Basically, you would declare an `extern` method:

```
[DllImport("yourlibrary.dll")]
static extern YourFunctionName(...)
```

The semantics of getting the marshaling correct is a bit tricky, but this [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120.aspx) page should get you started.